# When should shared NFS dir be unmounted?

Tags: server, mount, nfs, umount

I am using NFS services to copy files from the shared directory to another directory on the client (not part of the mount). I don't need NFS services to be running at all times so, once the files are copied,I simply stop NFS services, but I don't unmount the shared dir on the client. Next time I need to copy files I just enable services.
My question is, is this a good practice? Do I need to unmount each time I turn off NFS services?

Comment: Unmounting may be more important when you copy files to the mounted location. Unmounting writes the write-cache to disk. If you just stop the service, parts of the files to be copied may remain in the write-cache and the copied files may be corrupted. This is from my knowledge of hard drives. NFS may be different.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would set a user for the share, and keep the service online entirely, unless it is strenuous on your system. This way you would not need to continue to login to the server, as well as it secures the mount, with a password-protected user.